# Wallpaper is not setting up once set one wallpaper

Tags: android, android-studio, live-wallpaper

I have a video wallpaper app in which I am trying to set the live wallpaper for the first time it works fine. But the second time it does not change the wallpaper unless I restart the device.

I tried using "wallpapermanager.clear" function as well but the problem with that is if the user doesn't set the wallpaper the previous wallpaper gets removed automatically.

I don't want the previous one to get removed.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
vintent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT,
    new ComponentName(this, MyWallpaperService.class));
vstartActivity(intent);

try {
    WallpaperManager.getInstance(this).clear();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save Your changes On `SharedPreference` of your `WallPaper` Class i.e `MyWallpaperService` use below code and modify according to your need hopefully its help... `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` use to save data both previous and updated you just need to set condition when you want update

```
class MyWallpaperService :WallpaperService() {

    /**
     * Service Starting Hierarchy
     *      1) Service:         onCreate()
     *      2) Service:         onCreateEngine()
     *          i) Engine:              onCreate()
     *          ii) Engine:             onSurfaceCreated()
     *          iii) Engine:            onSurfaceChanged()
     *          iv) Engine:             onVisibilityChanged()
     *          v) Engine:              onTouchEvent()                  // if any
     *          vi) Engine:             onSurfaceDestroyed()
     *          iii) Engine:            onDestroy()
     *      3) Service:         onDestroy()
     */

    override fun onCreateEngine(): Engine {
        return MyWallpaperEngine()
    }

    private inner class MyWallpaperEngine : Engine(), SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

        // A reference to our shared prefs;

        override fun onCreate(surfaceHolder: SurfaceHolder?) {
            super.onCreate(surfaceHolder)


            // Create an instance of CustomEngine
            val customEngine = MyWallpaperEngine()
           // Register the listener to start listening for shared preference changes
            customEngine.registerSharedPreferencesListener()

        }

        // Method to register the listener
        private fun registerSharedPreferencesListener() {
            val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
            sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)
        }

        // Method to unregister the listener
        private fun unregisterSharedPreferencesListener() {
            val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
            sharedPreferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)
        }

        override fun onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy()

            // Unregister the shared preferences listener to avoid memory leaks
            unregisterSharedPreferencesListener()
        }
        override fun onSharedPreferenceChanged(
            sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences?,
            key: String?
        ) {
           //your Changes data 
           //Rest of Code
        }
    }
}
```